# CHCSV parser loading data into iOS app very slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, csv

I am using Dave Delong's CHCSV parser to load data into an iOS app from a CSV file into a database. The app is one that I am updating for work.
I have found that the app seems to take a long time to load all of the data into the app. There are just over 13000 lines of data and that takes about 10 minutes to load.

I do not have a lot of experience with CSV parsing or Objective-C, but I've been trying to get this app to run faster. When I first started working on it, the parser was the original that Dave put on GitHub, but I have since updated it to his most recent commit, but this change only dropped the load time from 15 minutes to 10 minutes.

All of the data is being collected and I don't have any issues with that, I would just appreciate some insight into why I am having such a problem with load time. I have not made any changes to the code from Dave.

If anyone has had this problem or knows a solution that could work, I would greatly appreciate it. I've spent quite some time combing the web for help, but no one seems to be having issues with load time. I'm not sure if any code of mine could be causing an issue, so if any code snippets are needed to help me, I am more than willing to give them.

Here is the code with JSON:

```
NSString *url = [_configDictionary objectForKey:@"stationCSVURL"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[url release];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
[request release];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
[data release];
[self clearDatabase];
int count = 0;
for (NSObject* stations in tempDict) {
    NSLog(@"%i", count);
    _station = [[StationInfo alloc] init];
    NSString *tempID =[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"ID"][count];
    if(tempID && (tempID != [NSNull null])){
        _station.iD = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"ID"][count] intValue];
    }
    else _station.iD = 0;
    NSString *tempName = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Title"];
    if(tempName && (tempName != [NSNull null]) && [tempName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        _station.name = tempName;
    }
    else _station.name = @"N/A";
    NSString *tempAddress = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"AddressLine1"];
    if(tempAddress && (tempAddress != [NSNull null]) && [tempAddress isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        _station.address = tempAddress;
    }
    else _station.address = @"N/A";
    NSString *tempCity = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Town"];
    if(tempCity && (tempCity != [NSNull null]) && [tempCity isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        _station.city = tempCity;
    }
    else _station.city = @"N/A";
    NSString *tempState = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"StateOrProvince"];
    if(tempState && (tempState != [NSNull null]) && [tempState isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        _station.state = tempState;
    }
    else _station.state = @"N/A";
    NSString *tempZip = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Postcode"];
    if(tempZip && (tempZip != [NSNull null]) && [tempZip isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        _station.zip = [[[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Postcode"] intValue];
    }
    else _station.zip = 0;
    NSString *tempPhone = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"ContactTelephone1"];
    if(tempPhone && ![tempPhone isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        _station.phone = tempPhone;
    }
    else _station.phone = @"N/A";
    NSString *tempComments = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"AccessComments"];
    if(tempComments && ![tempComments isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        _station.daysTime = tempComments;
    }
    else _station.daysTime = @"N/A";
    NSString *tempLat = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
    if(tempLat){
        _station.latitude = [[[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
    }
    else _station.latitude = 0;
    NSString *tempLong = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
    if(tempLong){
        _station.longitude = [[[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"AddressInfo"][count] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];
    }
    else _station.longitude = 0;
    if([tempDict valueForKey:@"UsageType"][count] != [NSNull null]) {
        NSString *tempUsage = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"UsageType"][count] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        if(tempUsage){
            _station.publicOrPrivate = tempUsage;
        }
        else _station.publicOrPrivate = @"N/A";
    }
    NSDictionary *tempDict2 = [tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"Connections"][count];
    NSString *tempConnect = [[tempDict2 valueForKeyPath:@"ConnectionType"][0] objectForKey:@"Title"];
    if(tempConnect){
        _station.connectionType = tempConnect;
    }
    else _station.connectionType = @"N/A";
    count++;
    if(count % 100 == 0) NSLog(@"%i stations loaded.", count);
    if (_station.name) [self addStationToDatabase:_station];
    [_station release];
}
```

Comment: CSV parsing is expensive and time-consuming. Some solutions: (1) split the CSV file into smaller files, do the work on a background thread, and show the user data as it gets parsed (2) convert the data to JSON and import that instead, (3) if the data is mostly unchanged, import it to your database, then embed the database file in your app when it ships

Comment: @AaronBrager I'm going to take your recommendation and switch it over to JSON. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. If you have a lot of data, it still will take some time but in my experience should be faster than CSV. If it's still too slow, you may wish to measure and compare XML.

Comment: @AaronBrager I've implemented NSJSONSerialization for my app, however it seems to being using an insane amount of memory to the point where it is crashing the app. Any ideas as to why this is occurring? I can post some code if necessary.

Comment: I don't think it should be crashing, sounds like a bug. Sure, post the code (and a link to the JSON file, if you can)

Comment: @AaronBrager I posted the code and here is the link to the JSON file: [link](http://api.openchargemap.io/v2/poi/?output=json&countrycode=US&maxresults=14000)